# ng idle keepalive detect activity

Tags: angular, ng-idle

I use angular ng-idle, (core and keepalive) and I want to detect when user is active.
I search but cannot find any documentation that tell me when each ng-idle event occurs.
I can see examples of how to catch user **inactivity**,
But I want to catch the exact opposite - the times that the user **performs actions**, and then reset my timers.

How can I do it using ng-idle?
Which event can I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did some debugging and found the answer myself:
The `onInterrupt` event occurs in every user activity,
So this is the right event.